# How to call a class pointer function

Tags: c++, class, pointers

So basically I have 2 classes, BSTNode class and BST class, BSTNode is friend of BST.

In my BST class , I have these public functions

---

```
void BST::Insert(int val);
{
..do stuff
}
```

---

```
void BST::PostorderDFT(BSTNode* node)
{
 ...do stuff
}
```

---

I know that I have to create an object. Lets say :

---

```
int main(void)
{
 BST bst1;

//then use the object I just created to create a tree. Lets say:
{
bst1.Insert(1);
bst1.Insert(2);
bst1.Insert(4);
bst1.Insert(10);
ect..
```

So my question is, how can I call the PostorderDFT(BSTNode* node) function in main function. Or what argument should I pass to make it work because the parameter (BSTNode* node) is a class pointer, so it is quite hard to understand.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a variables of BSTNode like this:

```
BSTNode node;
```

You  can use a constructor as follow:

```
BSTNode node(0,NULL,NULL);
```

Then, You can assignment for this variables as usual,Finally,You can use this variables like this:

```
// some assignment 
// ...
bst1.PostorderDFT(&node);
```

Comment: Thank you. That helped. Also, lets say if I have this tree 
   (1)-root 
(2)  (4)
            (10)

how can I assign my node equal to node (4) after I create a BSTNode object. Or, if I want to calculate the height of the tree at node(4) ect.

Again, thank you so much for helping me out.

Comment: This question is on the basis of your BST's implement.